# RuntimeBrowser Class Dumping

Tags: class, header, runtime, dump

How do I use RuntimeBrowser to output data like this ( https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers )??  I have some older firmware not found on the GitHub repo above and I have some builds of iOS that I would like to class dump.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ensure that you have an iOS device and a computer on the same network
- start [OCRuntime](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser) on an iOS device
- in the `Frameworks` tab, hit `Load All`
- check the URL in the `About` tab, say `http://192.168.2.3:10000`
- on the computer, enter `wget -r http://192.168.2.3:10000/tree`
- the computer should download all the 20000+ headers in 15-20 minutes

Comment: I had to add a last trailing slash for it to download all files. So instead of `..:10000/tree` I had to do `..:10000/tree/`